# PrimeFaces: <p:inline> inside <p:dataTable> not function properly on ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, button, primefaces

In my application, I use PrimeFaces's `<p:inline>` inside `<p:dataTable>` component to implement update feature as following:

```
<p:dataTable var="m" value="#{mrBean.menu}">

   <p:column headerText="Name" >
      <p:inplace editor="true" >
         <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{mrBean.changeName}" update="button" />  
         <p:inputText value="#{m.name}" />  
      </p:inplace>
   </p:column>

</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton id="button" value="Confirm" actionListener="#{mrBean.confirm}"
                 disabled="#{not mrBean.canConfirm}"/>
```

And this is my Managedbean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mrBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MrBean {
   private List<Meal> menu;
   private boolean    canConfirm;

   public void changeName() {
      this.canConfirm = true;
   }

   public void confirm() {
      System.out.println("Updated database!");
   }
}
```

When I finished editing `name` and clicked Save, my Eat button was not enabled.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me what I have done wrong here. I am using PrimeFaces 3.0.RC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<p:inline>` cannot be used inside `<p:dataTable>` to edit. What I should use instead is [`<p:cellEditor>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableEditing.jsf).

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me,

I guess you omitted some code from the one you posted on purpose, but if not, will post the one I generated beside the one you posted...

```
private String  someText ="xxx";


public String getSomeText() {
    return someText;
}

public void setSomeText(String someText) {
    this.someText = someText;
}

 public boolean isReadyToEat() {
    return readyToEat;
 }

public void setReadyToEat(boolean readyToEat) {
    this.readyToEat = readyToEat;
}
```

and wrapped the code of the xhtml with `<h:form>`

and it works 100%

output is

> Ready to eat: true
>
> YUMMY!

Comment: You're absolutely right that my example works 100%. I will update my question with more proper code tomorrow. Thanks to you, I found out the problem :P!

Answer (score 0):

You must have boolean `isReadyToEat() {return readyToEat;}` method in your bean (and `String getSomeText()` , `void setSomeText(String text)`). You also need to place *commandButton* and *inplace* inside *form* tag.

If the button becomes enabled after refreshing page in browser you probably need

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="button" />
```

within *inplace* tag.

Comment: This will not work. 1st of all, I do not need to submit the whole form. Besides, I am using PrimeFaces, I should only use `<p:ajax>` in the middle of PrimeFaces's other tags.